# Get variable from ItemRenderer to Main Application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a List with TextInput as item renderer. I want to get the value entered in the TextInput (form the TextInputItemRenderer) and pass it the main application to do some checks(upon tapping enter on the textInput -- see code below).

I know that we can do it thru dispatching event but I still don't understand how to pass a variable from the ItemRenderer to the main app.

Help Pls.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" xmlns:components="components.*" width="100%"
                >

    <s:layout> 
        <s:HorizontalLayout/> 
    </s:layout> 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
                super.data = value;
            }

            protected function myTextInput_enterHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

                trace(myTextInput.text);
                                What Next??


            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <components:ClearableTextInput text="{data.label}" id="myTextInput" enter="myTextInput_enterHandler(event)"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get changed value of Item from ItemRenderer in List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437634/get-changed-value-of-item-from-itemrenderer-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if I got your question correctly but would this help?

http://www.ajibanda.blogspot.com/2011/02/changing-currentstate-of-main-and.html

Comment: After having input some text in the TextInput (which is the itemrenderer) in the list, I actually want to commit the changes so that in my main Application I can do getItemAt() to obtain the changed value at that particular index.

Am I clear enough?

Comment: so generally you want to get the text from the TextInput right? doesn't myTextInput.text return it? and what does your ClearableTextInput looks like?

Comment: Yes myTextInput.text returns it...but this is in the itemRenderer. So if I put myTextInput.text in a variable, how can I access this variable from my mainApplication?



My ClearableTextInput is as such:



package components {
 
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 
 import mx.events.FlexEvent;
 
 import renderers.TextInputRenderer;
 
 import spark.components.Button;
 import spark.components.TextInput;

  
 public class ClearableTextInput extends TextInput {
 
  
  public function ClearableTextInput() {
   super();
   
   
  }
 }
}

Comment: try this FlexGlobals.topLevelApplications.[id of your itemRenderer].text

Comment: make sure to add import mx.core.FlexGlobals;   on your mainApplication

Comment: you can see from the link I posted the complete way to use this, only that it gets the currentState, but it should work similarly

Comment: I tried it..it doesnt work..it says "Property [itemrenderer name] not found on [mainApp] and there is no default value.

By the way, the List has several items which are rendered in TextInputs, so basically the way you are telling me, it will not know from which index to read the value of the item.

Any other solution?

Comment: The answer is Here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437634/get-changed-value-of-item-from-itemrenderer-in-list

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access from MainApp to itemRenderer, i think you can do backward. Follow one of two solutions below:

1. In itemRenderer, assign value you want to check later to a public global variable on the MainApp. The limitation is you then only enable to check it on MainApp, not any where esle (other itemRenderer, component, module etc.)
2. Use EvenBus to put the value to a global container. Create a static eventBus instance in AppUtils, for example. In itemRenderer, AppUtils.eventBus.dispatch() an event with the value attached to it each time the value changed. And then use AppUtils.eventBus again to addEventListener() to retrieve the value and check wherever you want. Google AS3Commons for EventBus.