# Get changed value of Item from ItemRenderer in List

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a List with textInput as itemrenderer. Initially the list is loaded with data from a data provider. However since the items are rendered in textInputs, I have the ability to change the value of a particular item.

But when trying to access the value of the changed item using the function below, I still get the old value in my trace:

```
private function addItem(event:Event):void {
    trace(myDataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);
}
```

can someone tell me what I need to do for the new value to be available. My itemrenderer  is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                xmlns:components="components.*"
                >
<s:layout> 
    <s:HorizontalLayout/> 
</s:layout> 

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
            super.data = value;
        }

        protected function myTextInput_enterHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            trace(myTextInput.text);
                            What Next??


        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<components:myComp1 text="{data.label}" id="myTextInput" enter="myTextInput_enterHandler(event)"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Thanks for your help..anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                xmlns:components="components.*"
                >
<s:layout> 
    <s:HorizontalLayout/> 
</s:layout> 

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
            super.data = value;
        }

        protected function myTextInput_enterHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            trace(myTextInput.text);
            data.label = myTextInput.text;
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<components:myComp1 text="{data.label}" id="myTextInput" enter="myTextInput_enterHandler(event)"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: I have tried setting, the following line,

data.label=myTextInput.text

But it still doesn't work. When doing the following in the main application..it still gives me the old value:

trace(myDataProvider.getItemAt(1).label); //for the index that I am testing and changing its value)
OR
trace(myDataProvider.getItemAt(myList.selectedIndex).label);



Anything missing here?

Comment: Place breakpoint into the `myTextInput_enterHandler` handler and see what happens (what variables are changes with what values). I think you've missed something obvious.